# Why do people say being a Dragonwrought Great Wyrm gives +3 mental stats?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, dragons

I'm trying to make a Dragonwrought Kobold Sorcerer, and people keep saying that it's awesome because you can "basically get +3 on all mental stats for free due to old age." I know that being Dragonwrought means you get no penalty for old age, but for as far as I can find in handbooks, the bonuses to mental stats don't go beyond +1 on each. 
Is this different for Kobolds, or am I missing something vital here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Age](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/description.htm#age) effects are cumulative

[Age](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/description.htm#age) affects a creature as follows:

> With age, a character’s physical ability scores decrease and his or her mental ability scores increase (see Table: Aging Effects). **The effects of each aging step are cumulative.** However, none of a character’s ability scores can be reduced below 1 in this way.

Hence a venerable kobold with the feat Dragonwrought (*Races of the Dragon* 100) sees its Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma increase by +3 but suffers no penalty to Strength, Dexterity, or Constitution because Table 3–2: Kobold Age Categories includes the footnote, "Ability penalties due to age do not apply to dragonwrought kobolds" (*Races of the Dragon* 39)